# How do you select from a reference table with exclusivity?

Tags: database, postgresql

I've got two tables (`threads` and `user_threads`). Essentially, a thread is an object with a name, and then a user_thread links a user to a thread. This was to illustrate a many-to-many relationship.

Given this setup, Im trying to figure out how to get threads between exclusively two users.

Threads looks like this

```
|------------------------|
| id    |  name          |
| 1     | group1         |
| 2     | test group     |
|------------------------|
```

user_threads looks like this

```
|---------------------------------|
| id    | user    | thread        |
|---------------------------------|
| 1     | 1       | 1             |
| 2     | 2       | 1             |
| 3     | 1       | 2             |
| 4     | 2       | 2             |
| 5     | 3       | 2             |
|---------------------------------|
```

So the issue that I'm running into is this - Given user 1 and user 2, I would like to return the mutual thread that is exclusive to them.

Querying with 1 and 2 should return thread 1. I've tried using a self join and mixing exclude, but SQL is not in my primary skill set. Is there any way to do this or do I need to restructure my tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to select the threads that have both users using a JOIN and then excluding all those that have other users in them also.

```
SELECT ut1.thread FROM user_threads ut1
  JOIN user_threads ut2 ON ut1.thread=ut2.thread
  WHERE ut1."user" = 1 AND ut2."user" = 2
    AND NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT 1 FROM user_threads WHERE thread=ut1.thread AND "user" NOT IN (ut1."user", ut2."user"))
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fd662/2/0)

Comment: Hey! This seems to work and is really helpful! I didn't realize you could use `IN` with subqueries! Thanks for the prompt response!